# One more message then expected when using AsyncProcessor

Tags: apache-camel

I tried to use AsyncProcessor in test scenario, expecting only one message to run through route, but seems like there are two of them.

in log

```
Test0
Test1
```

Why there are two messages?

```
from("quartz:test?trigger.repeatCount=1&trigger.repeatInterval=100").setBody(simple("Test"))

            .process(new AsyncProcessor() {

                private volatile int i;

                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    AsyncProcessorHelper.process(this, exchange);
                }

                public boolean process(final Exchange exchange, final AsyncCallback callback) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class) + (i++), String.class);
                            callback.done(false);
                        }
                    }).start();
                    return false;
                }
            })
                .process(new Processor() {

                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Tests.class).info(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you only want it to run once, then set `trigger.repeatCount=0`

Comment: Thanks, haven't noticed that trigger.repeatCount param is zero-based.